# Adding a link inside scrolling popup disables all click events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, pointer-events

I have a popup I've created in d3.js, where it's basically a Div that I scale to 1 on a click-event, and scale to 0 on a second click event anywhere else (i.e. click-off event).

Without being able to post all the code in a reproducible example, here's the relevant code.

**The issue:**

The popup works fine, until a link is added within the popup html (this line: `"hello".link("https://www.google.com")`). When a click-able link is added, you can't scroll the popup and it appears that all pointer events are disabled.  I'm not sure what about adding a link would cause it to do this.

I've tried to use `href` instead of `.link` and it still does not work.

**javaScript:**

```
    var LeafletDiv = d3.select("#content").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "county2014Tooltip")  
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("scrollTop", 0)



 var events = mapG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(eventArray)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", 'events')
        .style("display", dateMatch)
        .style("pointer-events", "auto")
        .attr("classed", "visible")
      
        .on("click", function(d) { 
            console.log('first click!')
            $('body').css({
            overflow: 'hidden'
            });

        LeafletDiv.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9)
            .style("transform","scale(1)")
         
                var popInfo = '<br/>' + d.EventDate
                +  '<br/>' + "hello".link("https://www.google.com") //this causes it to break
                + '<br/>'
                             
                appendText.push(popInfo+ '<br/>' + '<br/>')
                                        
                })

            LeafletDiv
                .html( appendText.join(""))
                .style("pointer-events", 'all')
```

**CSS:**

```
div.county2014Tooltip { 
    word-wrap: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:inline-block ;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: which d3 version are you using? v6+ ?

Comment: i'm using: https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 have you tried after changing the style of parent element `body` ? like `overflow: 'auto'; height:100vh` etc

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your problem line to this:

```
var popInfo = '<br/>' + d.EventDate
+ '<br/><a href="https://google.com">hello</a>' //changed to a html link tag
+ '<br/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use the link method as it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link), and prefer the href property. Not sure if this would solve your problem, but is best practice anyway.
Good Luck!

Comment: thank you! would I just use the href tag in building the popup in var popInfo?

Comment: It is not the href tag, is the anchor tag with href property defined. For example:

<a href="https://google.com">This is a link to google</a>

Comment: shoot, still no luck. I will edit answer to let people know I've tried this .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this, or at least something that got it to work. I only put the link in the popup initiated by click, and that worked. When I put the link in both popups (the one initiated by hover and click), it broke.